# overwrite checkout onepage.html

Tags: magento2.4, checkout-page

How to overwrite vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/onepage.html ?

Plus, I have my own theme module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to overwrite it.

1. Add the new file.

   app/design/frontend/your-vendor/your-theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/onepage.html
2. Copy the onepage.html content to the added file.
3. Customize it.

Comment: is it possible to use requirejs-config.js ?
Because I saw some developers are using.
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Checkout/template/onepage.html': Own_moduley/template/onepage.html'
        }
    }
}